# WCF Service Connection Timeout at Host

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a wcf service and works great on local IIS but when i deploy it to web i get the connection time out error. I set the timeout to 10 minutes and same error. What else can i do ? The timeout is on client side.

The service is here [Service Online](http://www.drorhan.com/ws/service1.svc)

```
WCF Config file

   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LicenseServer.Service1Behavior" name="LicenseServer.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://www.drorhan.com:8000" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="LicenseServer.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:1:00"/>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

**Client config**

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"
                 establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

> Server stack trace:     konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenCommunicationObject(ICommunicationObject
>   obj, TimeSpan timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenTokenProviderIfRequired(SecurityTokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, TimeSpan timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>
>   konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken
>   currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   konum: System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel
>   channel, TimeSpan timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan
>   timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    konum:
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

**Update**

I get  connection aborted 10053 error from host

Comment: yes i can access and get the methods.

Comment: Judging by the trace, I'm assuming you mean the open timeout on the client. WCF has many timeouts. Perhaps you can post some sample configs?

Comment: It can be some issue on server side and then rather than service giving you real issue it is throwing time out.

Comment: @user978511 i tried some endpoints what must it be ?

Comment: I had this issue [once](http://final-proj.blogspot.com/2009/09/wcf-timeouts.html), maybe that will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many causes on your security token negotiation.

are you using window clientCredentialType in your message binding in internet environment.

[Enable the WCF tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx) would give you ability to know more detail of the logs.

Comment: How can i set the log directory in host?

Comment: Have you enable MessageLogging under Diagnostics folder using svcconfigeditor , you could name the log file.

Comment: Yes i have set logging but there is a save path, i just gave the file name but it doesnt save anything. I am asking the hosting firm.

Comment: after investigation i get the  connection aborted 10053 error

Comment: The hosting companys says we cant support web services. There is no problem at the service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some troubles with the negotiation. There is a negotiation timeout property(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751788.aspx) but maybe the problem is deeper than simply the timeout(firewall maybe).

have you tried to remove the following section on the server side:

```
 <identity>
    <dns value="localhost"/>
 </identity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the first config bits the entirety of your service config?

If so, that's possibly where your problem is.  Each timeout config setting in your client needs to be less than or equal to the config setting in your service.

If your service doesn't define these timeouts, then it uses the default timeouts which may not be what you're expecting.  Just defining them on the client side isn't enough.  They need to be defined in both places.

Comment: It's just the binding section. I changed only the 1 minute timeouts to 10.